# Get the method name from a java.util.function.Function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is it possible to get the method name of a java.util.function.Function. I would like to log each time the name of the method being used. The following example prints the Lambda object but I have not found an easy way to get the method name:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[]  args) {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ex.callService(Integer::getInteger, "123");
    }

    private Integer callService(Function<String, Integer> sampleMethod, String input) {
            Integer output = sampleMethod.apply(input);
            System.out.println("Calling method "+ sampleMethod);
            return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt there is one. What name do you expect if someone just passes in a lambda, what name should that expression have?

Comment: There is no way, as the lambda, which you're passing is almost identical to an anonymous class implementation which just calls a method in its overriden method

Comment: I would expect that somehow the Lambda expression holds this kind information and print the method name: getInteger()

Comment: @GeorgiosStathis, well, it doesn't have this information. What if the lambda you got is something along the lines of `i -> i.getMyValue().getInternal("Parameter")`? What name would you expect to see?

Comment: Hmm.. I should have studied this better. I expected that since inside the samplemethod object the apply method knows to which method to use the input parameter then the method name should be retrievable somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to think about, what you're actually doing, when passing a method reference. Because this:

```
Integer::getInteger
```

Is almost identical (there is a stack layer more with the below approach) to this:

```
s -> Integer.getInteger(s)
```

And above is again similar to the following:

```
new Function<String, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String s){
        return Integer.getInteger(s);
    }
}
```

And in the last snippet you clearly see that there is no logical connection to the called method `Integer#getInteger(String)`. Which explaind why it is impossible to do what you intend without introducing something new.